# Hooking an interface method with Frida in an Android application

Tags: android, frida

I'm trying to understand what an android application is sending over the network and as such am trying to hook into it with Frida, specifically a method called `storeKeys` .

I was able to perform the Android tutorial from Frida's website, so I know it's working. But when I issue this command, it tells me it hooked 0 functions:

```
frida-trace -U -i storeKeys com.vendor.app
```

I thus fired up `apktool` to get a readable set of source files and I could find `storeKeys` in two places. The first is the place where it gets called:

```
# virtual methods
.method public a(Ljava/lang/String;)I
    .locals 2

    const-string v0, "jwtToken"

    invoke-static {p1, v0}, Lkotlin/e/b/i;->b(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V

    .line 20
    invoke-virtual {p0}, Lcom/vendor/alljoynbridge/provisioning/f;->getProxyObject()Lorg/alljoyn/bus/ProxyBusObject;

    move-result-object v0

    const-class v1, Lcom/vendor/alljoynbridge/provisioning/ProvisioningMediationTransport;

    invoke-virtual {v0, v1}, Lorg/alljoyn/bus/ProxyBusObject;->getInterface(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;

    move-result-object v0

    check-cast v0, Lcom/vendor/alljoynbridge/provisioning/ProvisioningMediationTransport;

    .line 21
    invoke-interface {v0, p1}, Lcom/vendor/alljoynbridge/provisioning/ProvisioningMediationTransport;->storeKeys(Ljava/lang/String;)S

    move-result p1

    return p1
.end method
```

The second appears to be its declaration:

```
.class public interface abstract Lcom/vendor/alljoynbridge/provisioning/ProvisioningMediationTransport;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "ProvisioningMediationTransport.java"

# interfaces
.implements Lorg/alljoyn/bus/BusObject;


# annotations
.annotation runtime Lorg/alljoyn/bus/annotation/BusInterface;
    announced = "true"
    name = "com.app.standard.infrastructure.api.device.mediation.client"
.end annotation

.annotation runtime Lorg/alljoyn/bus/annotation/Secure;
.end annotation


# static fields
.field public static final INTERFACE_NAME:Ljava/lang/String; = "com.app.standard.infrastructure.api.device.mediation.client"

.field public static final OBJ_PATH:Ljava/lang/String; = "/Provisioning"


# virtual methods
.method public abstract storeKeys(Ljava/lang/String;)S
    .annotation system Ldalvik/annotation/Throws;
        value = {
            Lorg/alljoyn/bus/BusException;
        }
    .end annotation

    .annotation runtime Lorg/alljoyn/bus/annotation/BusMethod;
        replySignature = "n"
        signature = "s"
    .end annotation
.end method
```

What I'm most interested in seeing is the content of the `String` parameter given to `storeKeys`

It seems that because the method is virtual abstract, there is nothing for Frida to hook into.

What have I missed here?  
What would you suggest that I try next?

Comment: Are you sure the frida-trace command is correct? If I understood frida-trace correctly the `-i` parameter is for native functions, but you are searching for a Java method which would be the `-j` parameter.

Comment: Ah, I should read the documentation more carefully. But when I try with the `-j` switch, I get this error:

`{'type': 'error', 'description': 'Error: Invalid method query', 'stack': 'Error: Invalid method query\n    at enumerateMethods (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-model.js:12)\n   [...], 'fileName': 'frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/class-model.js', 'lineNumber': 12, 'columnNumber': 1}`

Comment: I would try `-j '*storeKeys'`

Comment: Alas, it does not change a thing, still the same error about an invalid method query

Comment: Looks like the query has to match [this regex](https://github.com/frida/frida-java-bridge/blob/5e3d80a2ee7579de511ed87b022b36984cdcd6d0/lib/class-model.js#L1154). Therefore `-j '*!storeKeys'` should work?

Comment: You are right, I also found it in the sources. I tried with `storeKeys!s` just for experimentation, but with your command or mine, I always get the same result: 
The app gets killed
The `frida-trace` fails because of this.

I'll experiment with other commands